# Logging into and communicating with a server from an iOS app...help!

Tags: iphone, communication, data-transfer

Hey everyone. I have a fair amount of experience developing iOS apps, but nothing much with web/server interacting apps. For a project at work, I am making an app that will let you login, and get pictures off from a server that will then be downloaded for display and review on the local device.

I need to get some pointers on the correct approach to take. Are there built-in classes that make doing something like this easy? Once the cogent is downloaded from the server, it will be viewed locally, so all I need is to get a point in the right direction for logging in and communicating with a server…from an iPhone.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me, I'm using [ASIHTTPRequest Librayry](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to communicate / download with Internet.

For example, for an news app I download latest news in JSON (with a PHP script on a web server) and store datas with SQLite. If you need a little explanation of JSON with iPhone, check [here](http://www.geckogeek.fr/json-sur-iphone-installation-et-exemple.html) (in french, but source codes are in english ^^)

When I need to download an image, I use ASIHTTPRequest and a queue to avoid downloading to much files at the same time.

If you want more information about a step, just say it.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

NURLConnection is your friend, along with its delegate methods.

Don't be lured by the temptation to use the -sendSynchronous method (which, now that I think about it, if you require authentication, you probably can't use anyway).